# HTC Sense Keeps Crashing Even After Factory Reset

Tags: htc-desire, htc-sense, updates, force-close

I just updated my HTC Desire today to the newest firmware. However, on booting up the phone I get this message saying:

```
Sorry!
-------------
The application HTC Sense (process com.htc.launcher) has stopped unexpectedly.
Please try again.
                                 Force Close
```

When you force close it pops up again in <1sec and keeps looping like this. Sometimes you can pull down the notification bar and open a text or email, but `com.htc.messaging` and `com.htc.mail` produce similar error messages.

I have googled for some answers, but the search and menu buttons do not work, I do not have an alternate window manager and cannot install anything using `adb` (permission is denied). I tried many hard resets and factory resets but to no avail. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Callium this was an official update? if so were you already on a custom rom?

Comment: @Dan: It was an official HTC update on an unrooted phone to 2.29.405.1. It went wrong and damaged some library that all HTC apps depending on, I think.

Answer (score 1):

OP fixed the issue with the following solution:

> **Edit:** I fixed it by following the instructions from [TheUnlockr - How To: Unroot the HTC Desire](http://theunlockr.com/2010/06/07/how-to-unroot-the-htc-desire/) and flashing [this ROM](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=869048) [[Direct Link](http://www.filefactory.com/file/b4a4027/n/RUU_Bravo_Froyo_HTC_WWE_2.29.405.5_Radio_32.49.00.32U_5.11.05.27_release_159811_signed.exe)].

---

<sup>Community wiki under "best-practices" defined by this [meta answer](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1034/16265).</sup>